# Can i make ubuntu server do a system beep when ubuntu is ready to log in

Tags: system

So I'm using a ssh conection to log in and I need to know when ubuntu booted and it's ready for log in so I want to hear a beep when I can.

Answer (score 0):

Looks you need just to know when ssh is started. I see solution to stop ssh server autorun and make script with 2 steps **run ssh** + **beep** command.

1. Be sure **beep** is work.

`sudo apt install beep`. Then check. If isn't heart beep, `run sudo modprobe pcspkr` and then `beep`.

2. Create script which run ssh and beep (Example: sshrun):

   `#!/bin/bash
   update-rc.d ssh defaults
   systemctl enable ssh.socket
   beep`
3. Place the script you want to run in the /etc/init.d directory and make the script executable.

`chmod 755 sshrun`

*You need check all steps first in your system environment. And сorrect each if needed.*

Comment: soo i cant install beep Package beep is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Comment: That's a different and unrelated question. Look up how to enable the Universe repository.

Comment: @mature any kind hint is welcome. I have a Lenovo M73 thinkcentre with ubuntu server 22.04. When it POST it makes one beep, so pc speaker works. I have modprobe the pcspkr and removed from blacklist `pcspkr` and `snd_pcsp` but no way, if I run `beep` command I get `Could not open any device`. Do you have any kind suggestion to debug this?